# ASP.NET MVC Application on Ajax request with Kendo Chart with large datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI Charts for ASP.NET MVC and am providing a List of Data Transfer Objects to it to populate the data via an Ajax request. The issue however lies with the size of the list. I have approximately 3900 dtos within this list (as it is parsed from a file) and there are 9 objects within each dto:

```
public DateTime Time { get; set; }

public int BeatsPerMinute { get; set; }

public double Speed { get; set; }

public int Cadence { get; set; }

public double? Altitude { get; set; }

public int Power { get; set; }

public int? PowerBalance { get; set; }

public double Distance { get; set; }
```

I require all items within each dto, however when I send the Ajax request my browser timesout. I've set my web.config jsonSerialization maxJsonLength to 50000000, however that hasn't worked.

What's the recommended approach regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't my services or json causing the issue as when I stepped through the code, everything was fine. It seemed to be the fact that I was trying to render 23400 DOM elements at once on the page when I was populating the Kendo UI Chart. By disabling the plots for each item within the dto (not including power balance) and just showing the line, I was saving the loading of 19500 DOM Elements.

```
series.Line(a => a.BeatsPerMinute).Markers(c => c.Visible(false));
series.Line(a => a.Altitude).Markers(c => c.Visible(false));
series.Line(a => a.Cadence).Markers(c => c.Visible(false));
series.Line(a => a.Power).Markers(c => c.Visible(false));
series.Line(a => a.Speed).Markers(c => c.Visible(false));
```

Then there was the DateTime. There were 3900 dtos within the list, meaning I was rendering 3900 DateTime values in the chart. By providing a step of 30 (in my case, 30 seconds as each DateTime value was a second apart) I was saving nearly all of the remaining 3900 objects from loading.

```
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis
.Categories(a => a.Time)
.Labels(l => l.Rotation(-90)
.Step(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use asp.net mvc 3.0, it ignores maxJsonLength in web.config. Use in controller:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = Result, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears that setting the MaxJsonLength doesn't help. My page still becomes unresponsive.

Comment: If problem in json length, than you see an error message. Seems than there is timeout in controller action. Try set breakpoint in return. How long it takes to calculate result?